# is there a way of returning a list of items using find method in beautiful soup?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to scrape this url "https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=Machine+Learning&txtLocation=" and find the job description, key skills, location, years of experience and name of company but am having some issues.
when i print(company_name) i get only the first company name but i want to grab all the company's names in that page. this also applies to other fields too like the job_description, location, years,etc.
so, how do i get all the information i need rather than just getting the first information of the first company.
below is my code:

```
page = requests.get(url)
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('ul',class_="new-joblist")


for item in items:
    company_name = item.find('h3',class_="joblist-comp-name")
    job_description = item.find('ul',class_="list-job-dtl clearfix")
    
    first= item.find('ul',class_="top-jd-dtl clearfix").find_all('li')[0].text 
    second = item.find('ul',class_="top-jd-dtl clearfix").find_all('li')[1].text 
    location= second.split()[1]
    years = first.split()[2]
```

this above is what i tried doing and the result as i earlier said was that i just got a company name, location, number of years,and job description of one company only. i want to grab all those details of all the companies in that url. how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('ul',{class:"new-joblist"})
```

Comment: i get this error when i write the code SyntaxError: invalid syntax and its pointing to the class in the curly brackets

Comment: put the class between quotes------>items = soup.find_all('ul',{'class':"new-joblist"})